# Passing Variables to a Golang Package

Tags: go, singleton

Given a package containing the following local variable and functions:

```
var bucket *gocb.Bucket

func Init(b *gocb.Bucket) {
    bucket = b
}

func DoSomething() {
    // do something with 'bucket'
}
```

Is it acceptable to call the `Init` function, passing in an instance of `bucket`, before calling `DoSomething`, which is dependent on the `bucket` variable?

Or, should `DoSomething` instead explicitly accept a `bucket` parameter, as follows:

```
func DoSomething(bucket *gocb.Bucket) {
    // do something with 'bucket'
}
```

I would prefer to instantiate a single instance of `bucket` at a package-level, and use it throughout the application life-cycle, as opposed to managing at a function-level. Is this acceptable from design, performance, etc., perspectives, or is there a preferred means of achieving this? Bearing in mind that `bucket` need only be instantiated once.

`DoSomething` will be called from a HTTP context; I would prefer that the HTTP handlers not have visibility on the `bucket` parameter, and instead instantiate `bucket` on application start-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, if your package *depends* on something external you *import* said thing. So, unless it's impossible for some reason, you should import the package that instantiates `bucket` and take it from there, either directly assigning it or in your package's `init` function.

```
import "my/other/pkg"

var bucket = pkg.InitBucket()
```

However, if it's impossible to determine what package will provision `bucket`, then your way is the way to Go. As an example, consider `database/sql` where SQL drivers have to be registered before they can be used.

In general, [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) does not apply to Go packages if that's what you had in mind.